# Base-64 error when trying to execute vNext deployment script

Tags: ms-release-management

Release Management 2013 writes "The input is not a valid Base-64 string" error message into the Application Event Log when it tries to execute my Power Shell DSC deployment script. Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

PS DSC Script:

```
$ConfigData = @{
    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
         }
   )
}

Configuration WebAppServer
{
    Node $AllNodes.NodeName 
    {
        File WebApplicationFiles
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Type = "Directory"
            Recurse = $true
            SourcePath = $applicationPath
            DestinationPath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test"
        }
    }
}

WebAppServer -ConfigurationData $ConfigData
```

Error message from the Application Log:

```
Timestamp: 9/29/2015 5:19:32 PM
Message: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. : \r\n\r\n   at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
   at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Helpers.CryptoHelper.GetDecryptedValue(String str, String containerName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Data.Helpers.CryptoHelper.DecryptString(String str, String cryptoContainerName, String key, Encryption encryption)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.ComponentProcessor.ReplaceConfigurationVariable(String content, Boolean isHideEncryptedVariable, String value, String token, Boolean isPassword)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.ComponentProcessor.ReplaceConfigurationVariablesImplementation(String content, Boolean isHideEncryptedVariable)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.ComponentProcessor.InstallComponentImplementation(Func`3 replaceConfigurationVariables, IDictionary`2 installers)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.DeploymentAgent.Services.Deployer.ComponentProcessor.DeployComponent()
Category: General
Priority: -1
EventId: 0
Severity: Error
Title:
Machine: CAE-ATX-TFS01
Application Domain: ReleaseManagementMonitor.exe
Process Id: 1932
Process Name: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Release Management\bin\ReleaseManagementMonitor.exe
Win32 Thread Id: 10148
Thread Name: 
Extended Properties:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this in the past. When you enter the password, make sure the password asterisks (`*****`) changes in length to a really long value. That's the indication that it properly encrypted the password. I've seen cases where the encryption event doesn't fire for whatever reason.

You can work around it by saving the template, closing it, reopening it, then typing the password again.

Comment: Got it! There was something wrong with the Deploy Using PS/DSC action in my template. The password field was acting as you described (was changing length to long value), but still something wasn't working correctly. When I deleted the action from template and then re-added it -- then deployment started to work as expected, executing my script and copying files. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I think i've seen this before when I use tab to navigate to the next field AFAIK the encryption does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you migrate your server or restore an older database?

**Try re-entering the password (any encrypted value) in the vNext action in the release definition**.

Release Management is trying to invoke the powershell action and is failing there, and it has nothing to do with your script. Possibly, the encrypted password field has been encrypted with a different key from what RM has now.

Comment: No and no. All software, including 2013 RM server, was installed on a brand-new VM directly, no upgrades or migrations.

Comment: I re-entered the password into the vNext action -- nothing changed, getting the same error message.